# tableHeaderCheckbox comes disabled on 1st load of the page using ptable

Tags: primeng

i am using ptable and in that header contains ptableHeaderCheckbox . By default when the page loads this header checkbox on the table header comes disabled. It gets enabled only if i click a checkbox  that is in the table body.

Tried all the examples from primeng table creation with checkbox that is available on primeng site.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know the solution, but found a work-around:

In html add a *ngIf to the table:
<p-table  *ngIf="tableVisible" ... >

In your component create a variable:
tableVisible = true;

After loading your data trigger table refresh like this:
// table reload trick
this.tableVisible = false;
setTimeout(() => this.tableVisible = true, 0);

The headercheckbox should not be disabled now.